# Object with empty attributes in collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have collection of objects fetched from database and when I itterate over it with .each method I get single object with only empty values, like this:

```
      - !ruby/object:List
        attributes:
          id: 4
          title: Test
          project_id: 10
          created_at: 2013-12-29 20:53:04.087839000 Z
          updated_at: 2013-12-29 20:53:04.087839000 Z
      - !ruby/object:List
        attributes:
          id: 5
          title: Testng
          project_id: 10
          created_at: 2013-12-29 20:53:59.087687000 Z
          updated_at: 2013-12-29 20:53:59.087687000 Z
      - !ruby/object:List
        attributes:
          id: 
          title: 
          project_id: 10
          created_at: 
          updated_at:
```

What is ok, but... in my SQLite3 database I have only two rows... As doing work around here is not any problem for me I would like to understand why it happens. Could you explain me please?

Here is my controller and partial view in which I am using @current_lists variable

**projects_controller.rb**

```
  def show
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])

    @attachment = Attachment.new
    @list = @project.lists.new

    @current_lists = @project.lists
    @current_attachments = @project.attachments
    @current_issues = @project.issues.includes(:category)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @project }
    end
  end
```

**_lists.html.haml**

```
- @current_lists.each do |project|
    .col-md-4
      .panel.panel-default
        .panel-heading
          =project.title
          .pull-right.text-success
            %a.fa.fa-plus.fa-lg
        %ul.list-group.task-list
          %li.list-group-item.selected
            %label.label-checkbox.inline
              %input.task-finish{checked: "checked", type: "checkbox"}/
              %span.custom-checkbox
            SEO Optimisation
            %span.pull-right
              %a.task-del{href: "#"}
                %i.fa.fa-trash-o.fa-lg.text-danger
        / /list-group
```

EDIT:
That is modal code that I use to render form which uses @list instance variable:

```
/ /Modal
#newList.modal.fade
  .modal-dialog
    .modal-content
      .modal-header
        %button.close{"aria-hidden" => "true", "data-dismiss" => "modal", type: "button"} &times;
        %h4 Modal with form
      .modal-body
        =form_for [@project, @list] do |f|
          - if @list.errors.any?
            #error_explanation
              %h2= "#{pluralize(@list.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this list from being saved:"
              %ul
                - @list.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
                  %li= msg

          .form-group
            = f.label :title
            = f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control input-sm'
          .form-group
            = f.submit 'Save', class: '.btn.btn-success'
    / /.modal-content
  / /.modal-dialog
/ /.modal
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating an empty list object in your projects controller with the code:

```
@list = @project.lists.new
```

A solution would be to only select saved objects from your `@project.lists` with:

```
@current_lists = @project.lists.to_a.select { |list| !list.new_record? }
```

This will remove unsaved records from your `@current_lists` array.

**Edited to include solution**

Comment: Ahhh! Yes, because I need to pass @list variable into form which is in modal that I render on the same page. How can I avoid such behavior? I will paste modal's code in question content, thank you!

Comment: I have just seen your edit. Thank you very much, it works like a charm!